# createNewElement and appendChild to existing content

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand JavaScript a little better and am having trouble creating elements and appending values to them.

All I want to do is create a new paragraph element, which will contain a new string, and add the paragraph to my existing div tag using appendChild.

```
var oldParagraph = document.getElementById('content')
var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
var text = document.createTextNode("i am a new text node.");

newParagraph.setAttribute('class', 'red');

function addText(){
     document.oldParagraph.appendChild(newParagraph);
     document.newParagraph.appendChild(text);
}
```

my HTML is simple:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be this:

```
function addText(){
     oldParagraph.appendChild(newParagraph);
     newParagraph.appendChild(text);
}
```

`oldParagraph` and `newParagraph` are variables containing DOM object references.  You operate on those DOM references directly.

In practice, I would think you'd organize your code more like this with local variables instead of global variables:

```
function addText() {
    var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    newParagraph.className = 'red';
    newParagraph.appendChild(document.createTextNode("i am a new text node."));
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(newParagraph);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/42ffq/.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Although what you posted is making complete sense to me, the new paragraph element is still not showing up in my div tag.

Comment: It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/42ffq/.  Are you waiting for the document to be loaded before calling `addText()`?

Comment: yes all is working fine, I simply forgot to call the addtext() function after declaring it. Thank you all for your help!